# Clojure Practice : Interleave - outOfmemoryError

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement 'interleave' for myself but get a outOfMemoryError

my version should be same as:

```
(interleave [1 2] [3 4])
```

Here is the code:

```
(defn myInterleav [col1 col2]
  (loop [r []
         c1 (first col1)
         c2 (first col2)]
    (if (and c1 c2)
      (recur (conj (conj r c1) c2)
        (next col1)
        (next col2))
      r)))

(myInterleav [1 2] [3 4])
```

Version 2 as 'noisesmith' suggested to rebind args, but get nullPointer error.

```
(defn myIL2 [col1 col2]
  (loop [m  []
         [e1 & c1] col1
         [e2 & c2] col2]
    (if (and e1 e2)

      (recur (conj m e1 e2)
             c1
             c2)
      m
    )))
```

Comment: For `(myIL2 [1 2] [3 4])`, I get `[1 3 2 4]`.

Comment: Would `(flatten (map list col1 col2))` do what you want - my thinking was that if you could take the corresponding items in each collection, join them in some way and then take the contents of the resulting collections as a whole, you'd get where you want to be. Almost certainly there's a better way, which I hope somebody will point out!

Comment: @CodeFarmer That should work unless false or nil is in one of your lists, I just updated my answer to fix that case.

Comment: @peter: flatten is a problem because of the case where you have lists as individual items in your input list. `(apply mapcat list colls)` is how I would implement this, but that doesn't really address his code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function never returns if neither input is empty, because the bindings for `col1` and `col2` cannot change. You need to rework your loop to rebind to the `next` of the previous binding each time, rather than the `next` of the initial function input. Something like this should work:

```
  [...
  [e1 & c1] col1
  [e2 & c2] col2]
(if (and (seq col1) (seq col2))
    (recur (conj r e1 e2)
           c1
           c2)
...)
```